# NSURLConnection and XCode "Build and Analyze"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have been following the documentation for using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) and am using delegates for managing the connection (overriding among other methods connection: `didFailWithError:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:`). The memory allocated for the `NSURLConnection` object is released in those delegate methods.

My problem is that running "Build/Build and Analyze" from the XCode menu triggers an annoying "Potential leak of an object (...)" warning in the method calling alloc on the `NSURLConnection` class (logically enough as I do not release it in the same block).

Is there a way to silence this warning?

Comment: Please show the method giving the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way round this to store the connection object in a retained instance variable. Then you can safely release it at the end of your first method.

Comment: Just for the sake of closing this one, I´ll settle on using an ivar. A lot of things have been happening with xcode and the sdk in the mean time, so this is perhaps not a big deal anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the Analyzer message it gives you more information, showing the path of execution etc.  Does this indicate that it's just being dumb or does it give you a hint as to what might be wrong?

Assuming the analyzer is just being dumb, I'd just keep the reference in an ivar if the message bothers you, then release it from within -dealloc.

Releasing an allocated resource from within a delegate method feels a bit voodoo to me in any case.  I'd even be tempted to move all of the code that's processing the NSURLConnection into its own class.

Comment: No it does not tell me anything more than what I already know: the release message is not sent in the method allocating the object, but in the delegate.

This is caused by the fact that the connection is released in the delegate methods, as explained in the apple documentation I refer to.

Keeping the reference in an ivar is probably a way to shut down the message, you´re right, but I would hope that there is another cleaner way to acheive my goal (correct memory management, no warnings).

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Florent on this one. "Listing 1" in Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) on NSURLConnection will flag a "potential leak" in "build and analyze". Yet putting a [theConnection release] at the end of the method crashes.

Would love to have someone comment on this for me!