# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with RestKit in didReceiveResponse method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, restkit

I can't get rid of a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in RestKit.  I suspect its because I have an ARC project and may be releasing the request or response variable too many times, but I've spent hours on this and am not sure.

My problem sounds similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802180/asynchronous-nsurlconnection-throws-exc-bad-access), but I'm not sure where in my code to make a similar change.

My implementation file has a straightforward method to post the new object to the server. All the mapping logic is down within the implementation file for the NSObject below:

```
-(void) createMeeting 
{
    NSString* baseUrl = @"https://myapp.appspot.com/api/meeting/?format=json&username=testuser@test.com&api_key=f8s9df8as8df9s8d97";
    RKObjectManager* rkoManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:baseUrl];    [NewMeetingRK initMap:rkoManager];
    NewMeetingRK *newmtg = [NewMeetingRK alloc];
    newmtg.leader = self.leaderEmail.text;
    newmtg.startdate = [sqliteformatter stringFromDate:bdate];
    newmtg.enddate = [sqliteformatter stringFromDate:edate];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:newmtg delegate:self];
```

And it successfully begins requestDidStartLoad:(RKRequest *)request
However it then crashes in RKResponse.m on the second to last line below (if ([[_request delegate] respondsToSelector:...  with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
    RKResponseIgnoreDelegateIfCancelled();
    RKLogDebug(@"NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: %ld", (long) [response statusCode]);
    RKLogDebug(@"Headers: %@", [response allHeaderFields]);
    _httpURLResponse = [response retain];
    [_request invalidateTimeoutTimer];
    if ([[_request delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveResponse:)]) {
      [[_request delegate] request:_request didReceiveResponse:self];
    }
}
```

Any ideas to help me?  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when a message is sent to an object that has been released.
You should pay attention to _request delegate object. NSZombieEnabled break point might help you too. [How to enable zombie objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Got it.  There was nothing wrong with the code above. The issue was a second method that added the object to my local database. It was being called before RKRequest was completed. Thanks